# How can i make the camera to lookat the next target and then rotate and move to the next target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script is just making the camera to move over the terrain this script i'm not changing anything. The second script is PatrolData with that i feed the first script with data. The last script is the LookAt that should rotate the camera just a bit before moving to the next target(waypoint).

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class FlyToOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Transform target;
     public float desiredHeight = 10f;

     public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
     public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
     public float flightAcceleration = 1f;

     public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
     public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
     public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;

     private Vector3 flightVelocity = Vector3.zero;
     private float heightVelocity = 0f;

     private void LateUpdate()
     {
         Vector3 position = transform.position;
         float currentHeight = position.y;
         if ((bool)target && flightAcceleration > float.Epsilon)
         {
             position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(position, target.position, ref flightVelocity, flightSmoothTime / flightAcceleration, maxFlightspeed, flightAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
         }

         if (levelingAcceleration > float.Epsilon)
         {
             float targetHeight = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position) + desiredHeight;

             position.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentHeight, targetHeight, ref heightVelocity, levelingSmoothTime / levelingAcceleration, maxLevelingSpeed, levelingAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
         }

         transform.position = position;
     }
 }
```

Then the data script:

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 [System.Serializable]
 public class PatrolData
 {
     public Transform target = null;
     public float minDistance = 5f;
     public float lingerDuration = 5f;

     public float desiredHeight = 10f;

     public float flightSmoothTime = 10f;
     public float maxFlightspeed = 10f;
     public float flightAcceleration = 1f;

     public float levelingSmoothTime = 0.5f;
     public float maxLevelingSpeed = 10000f;
     public float levelingAcceleration = 2f;
 }

 public class PatrolOverTerrain : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public FlyToOverTerrain flyOverTerrain;
     public enum PatrolMode { Clamp, Wrap, PingPong };
     public PatrolData[] patrolPoints;
     public PatrolMode mode = PatrolMode.Wrap;

     private int iterator = 0;
     private int index = 0;
     private float lingerDuration = 0f;

     public Vector3 distanceFromTarget;

     private void OnEnable()
     {
         if (patrolPoints.Length > 0)
         {
             lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
         }
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         int length = patrolPoints.Length;
         if (!flyOverTerrain) return;
         if (patrolPoints.Length < 1) return;
         if (index < 0) return;

         var patrol = patrolPoints[index];
         if (lingerDuration <= 0)
         {
             iterator++;
             switch (mode)
             {
                 case PatrolMode.Clamp:
                     index = (iterator >= length) ? -1 : iterator;
                     break;
                 case PatrolMode.Wrap:
                     iterator = Modulus(iterator, length);
                     index = iterator;
                     break;
                 case PatrolMode.PingPong:
                     iterator = Modulus(iterator, length * 2);
                     index = length - Mathf.Abs(length - iterator);
                     break;
             }
             if (index < 0) return;

             patrol = patrolPoints[index];

             flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
             flyOverTerrain.desiredHeight = patrol.desiredHeight;
             flyOverTerrain.flightSmoothTime = patrol.flightSmoothTime;
             flyOverTerrain.maxFlightspeed = patrol.maxFlightspeed;
             flyOverTerrain.flightAcceleration = patrol.flightAcceleration;
             flyOverTerrain.levelingSmoothTime = patrol.levelingSmoothTime;
             flyOverTerrain.maxLevelingSpeed = patrol.maxLevelingSpeed;
             flyOverTerrain.levelingAcceleration = patrol.levelingAcceleration;

             lingerDuration = patrolPoints[index].lingerDuration;
         }


         Vector3 targetOffset = Vector3.zero;
         if ((bool)patrol.target)
         {
             targetOffset = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
         }

         float sqrDistance = patrol.minDistance * patrol.minDistance;
         if (targetOffset.sqrMagnitude <= sqrDistance)
         {
             flyOverTerrain.target = null;
             lingerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
         }
         else
         {
             flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
         }

         distanceFromTarget = transform.position - patrol.target.position;
     }


     private int Modulus(int baseNumber, int modulus)
     {
         return (modulus == 0) ? baseNumber : baseNumber - modulus * (int)Mathf.Floor(baseNumber / (float)modulus);
     }
 }
```

And the lookat script

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour {

     //values that will be set in the Inspector
     public Transform target;
     public float RotationSpeed;

     //values for internal use
     private Quaternion _lookRotation;
     private Vector3 _direction;

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         //find the vector pointing from our position to the target
         _direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

         //create the rotation we need to be in to look at the target
         _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

         //rotate us over time according to speed until we are in the required rotation
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
     }
 }
```

All scripts are attached to the Main Camera. Until now it was working fine the camera moved between the targets. Now what i want to do is when the camera stop near each target just a bit before the camera start moving to the next target make a rotation to be facing to the target it's going to be moving to.

The problem is i don't know how to make it wait and how much and when to start the rotation in the LookAtCamera script.

Now what it does when running the game it's start rotating right away to the next target(in inspector i dragged for testing the second target).

My problem is how to work with the LookAtCamera script.

Answer (score -1):

Found how to do it.
First in the LookAtCamera script that attached it to the Main Camera i also check that there is a target existing in the Update function:

if (target)

so the Update function:

```
void Update()
    {
        //find the vector pointing from our position to the target
        if (target)
            _direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

        //create the rotation we need to be in to look at the target
        _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

        //rotate us over time according to speed until we are in the required rotation
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
    }
```

Then in the script PatrolData:
The script PatrolData can be attached to any gameobject in this case i attached it to the Main Camera too.

In the top of FlyToVerTerrain i added:

```
public LookAtCamera lookAtCamera;
```

Then in the Update function:

```
lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
lookAtCamera.RotationSpeed = 3;
```

Then at this part:

```
if (targetOffset.sqrMagnitude <= sqrDistance)
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = null;
            lookAtCamera.target = null;
            lingerDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            flyOverTerrain.target = patrol.target;
            lookAtCamera.target = patrol.target;
        }
```

In the end all the 3 scripts make that the camera will move to each waypoint(target), The camera will rotate and will face to the next waypoint before moving to the next waypoint.

Working perfect.